# My answer was deleted: Software Defined Radio wrongly considered as "software"?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

[This question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/static-gps-delivered-via-standard-antenna-port) wants a device that can send generated GPS signals over an antenna cable. I gave exactly that in my answer:

> You can achieve this using an SDR (software-defined radio). It's essentially a device that can be programmed to transmit any radio signal you want.
>
> [gps-sdr-sim](https://github.com/osqzss/gps-sdr-sim) is an open source Software-Defined GPS Signal Simulator. You'll find recommended hardware and build instructions on that website.

This answer got deleted promptly by @ArtOfCode with this comment:

> [image]

Now I recognise that I should have provided references to the actual hardware. So I edited my (deleted) answer to make it more obvious that an SDR is actually a real piece of hardware. It also happens to need some software to run, just like most typical hardware nowadays, but I put the link to the software between parentheses:

> You can achieve this using an SDR (software-defined radio). It's essentially a device that can be programmed to transmit any radio signal you want:
>
> [image: Nuand BladeRF board]
>
> These SDR boards are known to be able to produce GPS signals:
>
> - [bladeRF](http://nuand.com/) (pictured above)
> - [HackRF](https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/wiki)
> - [USRP](http://www.ettus.com/)
>
> (To configure one of those to send out GPS signals, you could use for example [gps-sdr-sim](https://github.com/osqzss/gps-sdr-sim), an open source Software-Defined GPS Signal Simulator.)

So, being unable to discuss this in the comments since they are disabled on deleted posts, I'm left with the following questions:

- Is this considered a valid answer now?
- Will it be undeleted?
- Am I allowed to repost an new version of a deleted answer?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your edits. I deleted your answer because, when I looked at it, it seemed like you were recommending software - the GitHub link in particular reinforced that impression, and hardware was only tangentially mentioned. Your edits have made the answer much clearer now. So, to answer your questions -

- Yes, this is a great answer now.
- Yes, I've undeleted it.
- No, please don't. If your answer has been deleted and you think it's valid now, you can either post here on meta like you have done, or you can use the "flag" link under the post, select "in need of moderator attention", and write a short note to the moderators to explain that you've made some edits, and you'd like the deletion reviewed in light of those.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know about the flag button, I might use it one day :-)